# Error: ORA-06550: line 4, column 205: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;

Tags: oracle, grails, database-migration, grails-plugin

I am trying to execute anonymous block from a **.sql** file. I get the following error:

Error:

```
ORA-06550: line 4, column 205:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

;
```

The anonymous block is as follows:

```
BEGIN
FOR CUR_VAR IN (select id from opco where countrycode in ('IT','PT','DE','ES','GR','UK', 'IE','NL'))
LOOP
insert into vfservice (id, opco_id, name, service_order, service_template, version, service_key, enabled) values (SEQ_SERVICES_ID.nextval, CUR_VAR.id, 'My Vodafone', 0, 'REMOTE_ANONYMOUS', 0, 'SELFCARE',1);
insert into vfservice (id, opco_id, name, service_order, service_template, version, service_key, enabled) values (SEQ_SERVICES_ID.nextval, CUR_VAR.id, 'Vodafone Cloud', 1, 'REMOTE_AUTHENTICATED', 0, 'CONTENTBACKUP',1);
insert into vfservice (id, opco_id, name, service_order, service_template, version, service_key, enabled) values (SEQ_SERVICES_ID.nextval, CUR_VAR.id, 'Vodafone Contacts', 2, 'REMOTE_AUTHENTICATED', 0, 'CONTACTS',1);
end LOOP ;
END ;
```

I am using grails 3.3.2 and database migration tool and oracle 10g.

Comment: How and when and by what is the block being executed when running in Grails?

Answer (score 0):

Just put / on the end of file :)

When you are running procedure in anonymous block you need to use this syntax:

```
declare

begin

end;
/
```

Comment: I get the same error after adding / at the end. any other issues in the above block? it shows error on the 1st insert statement line.

Comment: Have you tried to run this directly in database via sqlplus/sqldeveloper Or run sql from file directly in sqlplus?

Comment: yes, using sqldeveloper it gets executed successfully. Am I missing some setting used by the grails database migration tool? for stored procedures

Comment: Well, im oracle developer, so i can't help much more. I don't think it is oracle problem, but probably some connection settings.